# Cartesian image to polar coordinate

Tags: python, image, polar-coordinates

I know this question has already been answered a lot of time but i can't figure if what 'im doing is good or bad.

I got a file with defect position and image ID. image size are 96*96. Origin is (48,48)

```
imgID  X        Y
1      5        6
1      87       76
2      45       23
```

From this i calculate R and T

```
x,y = df.X-48,df.Y-48
r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
t = np.arctan2(y,x)
df["r"]=r
df["t"]=t
```

Then i create empty matrix of size 96*96 for each image, and for image 1 (for exemple) i assign value 0 at each coordinate (R,T)

When i plot my matrix my result are strange.. Am i missing something important?

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking, what are you trying to achieve? what is the expected vs actual result?

Comment: Sorry is this is not clear. I "just" want to transform a matrix which represent an image in cartesian coordinate in a matrix which represent the image in the polar  coordinate.. i don't know if this make more sense..  For exemple on this website u can transform the image: http://www.photo-kako.com/fr/polar-coordinate.cgi

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of your code please? What is `df.X` for example? How do you create the empty matrix and how do you assign values to it? Do you convert `R` and `T` to integers to make subscripts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are insistent on a Python solution, or you just want to get the job done. If the former, please just ignore me and my answer will sink to the bottom. If the latter, you can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, starting with this `colorwheel.png`:

[image]

Just use the following command in Terminal, or Command Prompt if on Windows:

```
magick colorwheel.png -distort depolar 0 result.png
```

[image]

It's a little *"off"* because my input image is not exactly square or centred, but you get the idea :-)

Replace `-distort depolar` with `-distort polar` to do the inverse transformation.

For versions prior to v7, replace `magick` with `convert` in the commands above.

Comment: unofrtunetly i need to do it with python because i got million image and i'll take too much time to make conversion

Comment: You can use Python Wand to do that. It is based upon Imagemagick and so has distort depolar/polar. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.3/. Search for distort in the image section at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.3/wand/image.html